# Using html templates inside chrome content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, handlebars.js

I need to use some relatively complex html inside chrome content script. It looks ugly inside .js file, so i decided to use some templating and select Handlebars. I know, i can precompile Handlebars templates, so there would be no CSP violation. But how can i inject precompiled templates to use them inside content script? Is there more elegant way to do this, than manually creating XMLHttp request for each precompiled template?

Comment: Please add what code you have

Comment: @acarroz5 it's kind of theoretical question. I can inject precompiled templates somewhere about it's described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401946/chrome-extension-inject-template-through-content-scripts But it does not seems elegant for me. So i wonder, what is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured it out. All we need - precompile handlebars templates and then inculde them, with handlebars runtime into manifest.json like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://targetsite.com/*"],
      "js": ["app/content.js", "handlebars.min-latest.js", "precompiled_tmpls.js"],
      "css": ["styles.css"]
    }
  ]
```

Then I'm able to use it inside content.js like this:`Handlebars.templates.[tempalate_name]()`
No additional code required